# Allow adminer.php in nginx configuration

Tags: php

I've installed symfony and use the nginx config from here https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/symfony/

How can I allow adminer.php to be run?

I tried:

```
    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /adminer.php /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
```